# TYPO3 not showing images in front end - regular content elements and ext:news

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

We've just moved a Typo3 v7.6.30 Website to a new server and although the Website has started up and working as expected, when we try to upload images to content pages, they aren't displayed.  When we turn debugging on, we can see that the media item has been loaded, but the 'type' property, which we would expect to be set to '2' is set to zero.  Other meta data properties such as height, width and MIME type are also unset.  So this explains why the image is not rendering in the template.

When we look at the 'sys_file_processedfile' table in the database, we can see that record for a 'preview' image has been created but no record for the processed image for the front end.  Also, the record for the image in the 'sys_file_metadata' doesn't have any properties set.

We have run the 'Convert image formats to jpg' test in the Install too and everything shows as okay.  Our 'Image Handling Settings' are set to 'Image Magick version 6 or higher' and the following options have been set in the configuration: -

```
[GFX][image_processing] = 1
[GFX][thumbnails] = 1
[GFX][thumbnails_png]
[GFX][gif_compress] = 1
[GFX][imagefile_ext] = gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pd
[GFX][gdlib] = 0
[GFX][gdlib_png] = 0
[GFX][im] = 1
[GFX][im_path] = /usr/bin/
[GFX][im_path_lzw] = /usr/bin/
[GFX][im_version_5] = im6
[GFX][im_v5effects] = 1
[GFX][im_mask_temp_ext_gif] = 1
[GFX][im_noScaleUp] = 0
[GFX][im_noFramePrepended] = 0
[GFX][im_stripProfileCommand] = +profile '*'
[GFX][im_useStripProfileByDefault] = 1
[GFX][jpg_quality] = 65
[GFX][png_truecolor] = 1
[GFX][colorspace] = sRGB
```

Has any one else come across this issue before? It looks as if the properties for the Processed images aren't being brought through to the front end or written to the database.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernd, thank you for your response.

We fixed the issue, php-fileinfo was not enabled on the new host. Strangely this was not detected by the install tool environment checker.

Thanks again.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you copy an installation you might have amismatch between files in filesystem and all Information about these files in TYPO3.

Updating the storage index could show unresolved `sys_file` records or index other files in place of the original.
Also the metadata might fail, especially if `ext:filemetadata` is not installed.

Furthermore the processed images:
Some possibilities:

1. all images in the FE are correct, but the orignal is missing and any resizing of the images results in boken images (the hash-values for processed images and the processed images are correct, the original is missing or the `sys_file` record is missing)
2. all processed images are broken. TYPO3 has records about all processed images, but the images do not exist in filesystem. (remove all temporary images in install-tool: the records are deleted and records and images are build anew)
3. the folder for processed images can not be written. Normaly TYPO3 then uses the original image, which is not possible if the image has been cropped.